# Group By Data at 15 minutes of interval with 1 minute data

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am using SQL Server 2014.

I am having following table which contains data for stocks minute wise.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HISTORICALDATA]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SYMBOL] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [DATETIME] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [O] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
    [H] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
    [L] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
    [C] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
    [V] [INT] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_HISTORICALDATA] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Tables contains data as following sample shown

```
SYMBOL  DATETIME    O   H   L   C   V
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ACC 2019-01-01 09:16:00.000 1512.30 1512.30 1507.00 1507.00 7398
ACC 2019-01-01 09:17:00.000 1506.35 1507.80 1503.00 1504.05 8120
ACC 2019-01-01 09:18:00.000 1504.25 1506.00 1504.00 1505.50 3487
ACC 2019-01-01 09:19:00.000 1505.00 1505.00 1503.10 1504.00 3138
ACC 2019-01-01 09:20:00.000 1504.95 1504.95 1501.20 1501.20 4567
ACC 2019-01-01 09:21:00.000 1500.30 1500.95 1498.00 1498.00 8522
ACC 2019-01-01 09:22:00.000 1498.00 1500.90 1498.00 1500.05 4462
ACC 2019-01-01 09:23:00.000 1500.85 1501.40 1500.00 1500.95 2006
ACC 2019-01-01 09:24:00.000 1500.85 1500.95 1500.00 1500.05 1400
ACC 2019-01-01 09:25:00.000 1500.90 1500.95 1499.00 1500.00 3484
ACC 2019-01-01 09:26:00.000 1499.20 1500.00 1499.00 1499.00 1960
ACC 2019-01-01 09:27:00.000 1499.60 1499.95 1498.00 1498.90 1903
ACC 2019-01-01 09:28:00.000 1498.50 1498.50 1496.40 1498.00 3060
ACC 2019-01-01 09:29:00.000 1497.05 1499.10 1496.75 1499.10 3522
ACC 2019-01-01 09:30:00.000 1499.35 1499.50 1498.35 1498.35 741
```

I tried with following query but it gave me wrong results

```
SELECT
    SYMBOL,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, MAX(DATETIME)),
    MAX(H),
    MIN(L),
    SUM(V)
FROM
    HISTORICALDATA
WHERE 
    SYMBOL = 'ACC' AND MONTH(DATETIME) = 1
GROUP BY
    SYMBOL,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0 ,DATETIME) / 15
ORDER BY 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DATETIME) / 15
```

I need out with each 15 minute interval with

```
SYMBOL, DATETIME, OPENOF15MIN, HIGHOF15MIN, LOWOF15MIN, CLOSEOF15MIN
```

If someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can help.

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=55c13a0708ff3f7998f393a264623254)**

```
Select [SYMBOL]
       ,DTR1 = min(case when RNO=1 then [DateTime] end)
       ,DTR2 = min(case when RNC=1 then [DateTime] end)
       ,O    = min(case when RNO=1 then O end)
       ,C    = min(case when RNC=1 then C end)
       ,H    = max(H)
       ,L    = min(L)
       ,V    = sum(V)
 From (
        Select *
              ,Grp = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By Symbol Order By tMin )
              ,RNO = Row_Number() over (Partition By Symbol,tMin Order By [DateTime])
              ,RNC = Row_Number() over (Partition By Symbol,tMin Order By [DateTime] Desc)
        From YourTable A1
        Cross Apply ( values ( (DateDiff(MINUTE,0,[DATETIME]) - 1) / 15 ) ) A2(tMin)
      ) A
 Group By Symbol,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
SYMBOL  DTR1                DTR2                O       C       H       L       V
ACC     2019-01-01 09:16:00 2019-01-01 09:30:00 1512.30 1498.35 1512.30 1496.40 57770.00
```

Comment: Let me check sir

Comment: @Hemal Had a typo should be  ,C    = min(case when RNC=1 then C end)

Comment: Yes sir, noticed that in edit and I also changed it in code. I am checking the full results.

Comment: I would like to add 09:30 in group 2, because its part of first 15 minute group. Currently its in 3 group. The time 09:16 is the completion time of first minute that starts at 09:15 so as last one, 09:29 minutes start and ends at 09:30. So all those minutes are of same group. We can ignore first 09:08 minute if we want to.

Comment: I think its working and I will figure it out. Thanks sir a lot. You are truly a genius.

Comment: @Hemal "genius"  my wife would dispute that :)    I did make an update

Comment: For me you are. Say hello to your wife. 